# What is the proper way to do multi-GPU inference with Pytorch?

Tags: pytorch, multiprocessing, pytorch-lightning, multi-gpu

I'm facing some issues with multi-GPU inference using pytorch and pytorch-lightning models.
At inference time, I need to use two different models in an auto-regressive manner. Since the auto-regressive steps are computationally expensive, I wanted to split my dataset into smaller parts and send them to several GPUs so it can run in parallel and decrease inference time by a factor similar to the number of GPUs used. The auto-regressive step is complex and use 2 different models (see code snippet below) so I can not use the standard pytorch-lightning test_step.
After computing the final output, I want to export the generated images batch as image files.

**The issue I'm facing**:  when looking at the saved images, I noticed that some of them are missing, i.e. generated images corresponding to some batches are not saved.

```py
import os
import hydra
import torch
import torch.distributed as dist
import torch.multiprocessing as mp
from hydra.utils import instantiate
from omegaconf import DictConfig



def ddp_setup(rank: int, world_size: int):
    os.environ["MASTER_ADDR"] = "localhost"
    os.environ["MASTER_PORT"] = "47144"
    dist.init_process_group(backend="nccl", rank=rank, world_size=world_size)
    torch.cuda.set_device(rank)


@hydra.main(version_base=None, config_path="../../configs", config_name="transfert")
def main(cfg: DictConfig) -> None:
    world_size = torch.cuda.device_count()
    mp.spawn(run_da, args=(world_size, cfg), nprocs=world_size)


def run_da(rank: int, world_size: int, cfg: DictConfig) -> None:
    ddp_setup(rank, world_size)

    # define models map location
    map_location = {"cuda:%d" % 0: "cuda:%d" % rank}

    # get eps model of source domain
    source_model = Model.load_from_checkpoint(
        cfg.source_model_path,
        map_location=map_location,
    )
    source_model.eval()
    source_model.to(rank)

    target_model = Model.load_from_checkpoint(
        cfg.target_model_path,
        map_location=map_location,
    )
    target_model.eval()
    target_model.to(rank)

    # load source and target datamodules
    source_datamodule = instantiate(cfg.source)
    source_datamodule.setup()

    test_data_sampler = torch.utils.data.distributed.DistributedSampler(
        source_datamodule.test,
        num_replicas=world_size,
        rank=rank,
    )
    dataloaders = {
        "val": source_datamodule.val_dataloader(sampler=test_data_sampler),
        "test": source_datamodule.test_dataloader(sampler=test_data_sampler),
    }

    for stage, dataloader in dataloaders.items():
        for batch in dataloader:
            x = batch["img"].to(rank)
            cond = batch["cond"].to(rank)

            with torch.no_grad():
                # compute output with several calls with source and target model
                for _ in range(100):
                    x = autoregressive_step(source_model, target_model, x, cond)

            # save output as images
            export_output(x, stage)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Hypothesis**: some batches sent to some GPUs were not saved/processed. I have been monitoring how batches are sent to the GPUs and it turns out that some GPUs received a lot more batches than others.

I followed some tutorials about multi-GPUs training but it seems that it is pretty different in the case of inference (Distributed Data Parallel does not seem appropriate as far as I understand), so I'm wondering if my code includes an obvious bug that can be fixed or if there is any good ressources about multi-GPU inference using pytorch / pytorch-lightning models.

Thank you for your attention,

Erik